# Cannot update a component (`TodoForm`) while rendering a different component (`TodoTask`). [SOLUTION] [React Redux To-Do App]

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

**WHILE WRITING THIS POST I REALIZED WHAT THE SOLUTION WAS**

Every time I dispatch a task to my store the following error occurs:
[image]

I have some idea of why it happens. It happens precisely when I try to get the to-do list using useSelector and then mapping through the list. However, the mapping is not the issue but rather returning a react component on the map function. It works just fine if I do not return a functional component and instead use HTML. So the issue, from my POV, is returning a react functional component while passing props to it on a map function.

Here's the code for my home component:

```js
    import Input from '../components/Input';
    import TodoForm from '../components/TodoForm';
    
    
    function Home() {
      document.title = "MyTodo | Home"
    
      return (
          <div className="App">
              <h1>MyTodo</h1>
              <Input />
              <TodoForm />
          </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Home;
```

The input component where the action is being dispatched on key down:

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { todoActions } from '../store/todo';

const Input = () => {
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleChange = (e) => setInputText(e.target.value)

    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        if (event.code === "Enter") {
            // if the expression is false, that means the string has a length of 0 after stripping white spaces
            const onlyWhiteSpaces = !inputText.replace(/\s/g, "").length;

            !onlyWhiteSpaces &&
                dispatch(
                    todoActions.addTask({ label: inputText, done: false })
                );
            setInputText("");
        }
    };

  return (
      <input
          type="text"
          onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyPress(e)}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          value={inputText}
      />
  );
}

export default Input
```

The TodoForm where I am using `useSelector` to get the todo list from the redux store and mapping thru it:

```js
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import TodoTask from "./TodoTask";


const TodoForm = () => {
    const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.todo.taskList);

     const renderedListItems = tasks.map((task, index) => {
         return (
             <TodoTask
                 key={uuidv4()}
                 task={task}
                 targetIndex={index}
             />
         );
     });

     return <div className="container">{renderedListItems}</div>;
};

export default TodoForm;
```

Finally the TodoTask component which is the child component being returned on the map function above:

```js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { todoActions } from "../store/todo";

const TodoTask = ({ task, targetIndex }) => {
    const {text, done} = task;

    console.log("Task: ", task);

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const removeTask = dispatch(todoActions.deleteTask(targetIndex))

    return (
        <div
            className="alert alert-primary d-flex justify-content-between"
            role="alert"
        >
            {text}
            <button type="button" className="btn-close" onClick={()=>removeTask}></button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TodoTask;
```

This is my first time facing this issue, and I know it has something to do with redux and how the useSelector hook forces a component to re-render. So the useSelector is re-rendering the TodoForm component, and since we are mapping and returning another component, that component is also being rendered simultaneously. At least, that is how I understand it. Let me know if I am wrong.

Things I have tried:

1. Wrapping the TodoTask in React.memo. Saw it somewhere as a possible solution to this kind of issue, but that did not work.
2. Passing `shallowEqual` as a second parameter on the TodoForm useSelector. This does prevent the page from going into an infinity loop, but the tasks show up empty but are being added to the redux store. However, with this method, the first warning stills shows up, and the <s>console log in the TodoTask component does not execute.</s>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Passing shallowEqual as a second parameter on the TodoForm useSelector. This does prevent the page from going into an infinity loop but the tasks show up empty but are being added to the redux store. However, with this method, the first warning stills shows up and the console log in the TodoTask component does not execute.

I realized what I was doing wrong while writing this part. The console log in the TodoTask component was working, but I had the browser console filtering for errors only. When I check the messages section, I saw everything working fine. Then when I checked the Task component, I noticed I was trying to read a property that did not exist and hence why the tasks had no text.

In other words, the solution was adding [shallowEqual](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#selecting-data-in-list-items-by-id:~:text=There%27s%20a%20problem,Let%27s%20try%20that%3A) as second parameter of the `useSelector` hook in my TodoForm component that was the one mapping thru the todo tasks array. As I said, useSelector forces a component to re-render. `shallowEquals` checks if the existing state isn't the same as we already had and avoids unnecessary re-renders, which can lead my application to exceed the maximum update length.

Code fix [Solution]:

```js
import { memo } from "react";
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import TodoTask from "./TodoTask";


const TodoForm = () => {
    // shallowEqual prevents unnecessary re-renders which can lead to an infinite loop
    // it compares the current state with the previous one, if they are the same, it does not re-render the component
    const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.todo.taskList, shallowEqual);

     const renderedListItems = tasks.map((task, index) => {
         return (
             <TodoTask
                 key={uuidv4()}
                 task={task}
                 targetIndex={index}
             />
         );
     });

     return <div className="container">{renderedListItems}</div>;
};

export default memo(TodoForm);
```

Honestly, I have been stuck on this since yesterday and I cannot believe I realize the solution just when I was about to ask for help. Hope this helps anyone else who faces a similar issue in the future.